# how to upgrade kubernetes from v1.10.0 to v1.10.11

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade, kubeadm

i installed kubernetes via kubeadm under the 1.9 and upgraded it to 1.10.0 a while back using `kubeadm upgrade`. i'm quite happy with 1.10.x and don't want to deal with potential issues with upgrading to anything newer just yet.

So i would like to upgrade to 1.10.11.

i tried

```
$ kubeadm upgrade plan v1.10.11
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[upgrade/plan] computing upgrade possibilities
[upgrade] Fetching available versions to upgrade to
[upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.10.0
[upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.10.11
[upgrade/versions] Latest stable version: v1.13.1
[upgrade/versions] Latest version in the v1.1 series: v1.1.8
[upgrade/versions] WARNING: No recommended etcd for requested kubernetes version (v1.13.1)

Components that must be upgraded manually after you have upgraded the control plane with 'kubeadm upgrade apply':
COMPONENT   CURRENT       AVAILABLE
Kubelet     5 x v1.10.0   v1.13.1
                          2 x v1.10.3   v1.13.1
                          1 x v1.10.5   v1.13.1
                          2 x v1.9.6    v1.13.1

Upgrade to the latest stable version:

COMPONENT            CURRENT   AVAILABLE
API Server           v1.10.0   v1.13.1
Controller Manager   v1.10.0   v1.13.1
Scheduler            v1.10.0   v1.13.1
Kube Proxy           v1.10.0   v1.13.1
Kube DNS             1.14.8    1.14.8
Etcd                 3.1.12    N/A

You can now apply the upgrade by executing the following command:

    kubeadm upgrade apply v1.13.1

Note: Before you can perform this upgrade, you have to update kubeadm to v1.13.1.

_____________________________________________________________________
```

it seems to want me to upgrade to 1.13!

how can i /just/ upgrade from my v1.10.0 setup to v1.10.11?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you need to upgrade `kubeadm` to match your target version.  This is sort of hinted at by `Before you can perform this upgrade, you have to update kubeadm to v1.13.1.`.

Comment: yeah, i already did:  `rpm -qa | grep kubeadm; kubeadm-1.10.11-0.x86_64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to upgrade my kubernetes cluster from 1.10.0 to 1.10.11.

```
[root@ centos]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                         STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-.ec2.internal             Ready     master    2m        v1.10.0
```

Here is the step by step instructions:

```
export VERSION="1.10.11"
export ARCH=amd64
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.10.11/bin/linux/amd64/kubeadm > /usr/bin/kubeadm

chmod a+rx /usr/bin/kubeadm
```

Now check the kubeadm upgrade plan

```
[root@ centos]# kubeadm upgrade plan
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[upgrade/plan] computing upgrade possibilities
[upgrade] Fetching available versions to upgrade to
[upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.10.11
[upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.10.11
[upgrade/versions] Latest stable version: v1.13.1
[upgrade/versions] Latest version in the v1.1 series: v1.1.8
[upgrade/versions] WARNING: No recommended etcd for requested kubernetes version (v1.13.1)

Components that must be upgraded manually after you have upgraded the control plane with 'kubeadm upgrade apply':
COMPONENT   CURRENT       AVAILABLE
Kubelet     1 x v1.10.0   v1.13.1

Upgrade to the latest stable version:

COMPONENT            CURRENT    AVAILABLE
API Server           v1.10.11   v1.13.1
Controller Manager   v1.10.11   v1.13.1
Scheduler            v1.10.11   v1.13.1
Kube Proxy           v1.10.11   v1.13.1
Kube DNS             1.14.8     1.14.8
Etcd                 3.1.12     N/A

You can now apply the upgrade by executing the following command:

kubeadm upgrade apply v1.13.1

Note: Before you can perform this upgrade, you have to update kubeadm to v1.13.1.
```

Now instead of upgrade apply to v1.13.1 you should use:

```
kubeadm upgrade apply 1.10.11

[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
[upgrade] Making sure the cluster is healthy:
[upgrade/config] Making sure the configuration is correct:
[upgrade/config] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[upgrade/config] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[upgrade/version] You have chosen to change the cluster version to "v1.10.11"
[upgrade/versions] Cluster version: v1.10.11
[upgrade/versions] kubeadm version: v1.10.11
[upgrade/confirm] Are you sure you want to proceed with the upgrade? [y/N]: y
.......
[bootstraptoken] Configured RBAC rules to allow the csrapprover controller automatically approve CSRs from a Node Bootstrap Token
[bootstraptoken] Configured RBAC rules to allow certificate rotation for all node client certificates in the cluster
[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-dns
[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-proxy

[upgrade/successful] SUCCESS! Your cluster was upgraded to "v1.10.11". Enjoy!
```

Now follow the official documentation of upgrade [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade-1-11/) and you will be able to get the system up and running:

Drain the master nodes using:

```
kubectl drain ip-.ec2.internal --ignore-daemonsets
```

Upgrade the kubelet and kubeadm package using:

```
yum upgrade kubelet-1.10.11 kubeadm-1.10.11 --disableexcludes=kubernetes
```

Restart kubelet and uncordon the host:

```
systemctl restart kubelet
kubectl uncordon $HOST
```

And now you will be able to get you system up and running:

```
[root@ip- centos]# kubectl get nodes
NAME                         STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-.ec2.internal             Ready     master    32m       v1.10.11
[root@ip- centos]# kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-deployment-75675f5897-pmmkc   1/1       Running   0          9m
nginx-deployment-75675f5897-wshgz   1/1       Running   0          9m
```

Comment: great! i was assuming that the plan was the be-all-and-end-all. i guess it woudl be nice for it to accept a version in the plan, but at least it works!

Comment: Yes currently it doesn't accept version in upgrade plan. However it is just to check on which version your cluster can be upgraded. You can apply the version while you are upgrading the cluster.